# What is the status of The Halmos Similarity Problem?

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, similarity

What is the general status of "The Halmos Similarity  Problem"(HSP) in Operator theory?For What conditions ,HSP has been solved?

Comment: It was resolved negatively by Pisier.